# Cannot connect to network with laptop

Tags: laptop, networking, ethernet

I can't connect to network via an ethernet cable, but the wireless connection works fine.  This only happens on this laptop -  the pc network cable connection is fine.

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr my mac address
          inet6 addr: my inet6 address Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:5733 (5.7 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:49690 (49.6 KB)  TX bytes:49690 (49.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:df:9a:be:b7:0a  
          inet addr:46.237.123.248  Bcast:46.237.123.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:6800:0:125:d2df:9aff:febe:b70a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::d2df:9aff:febe:b70a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1857 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5518132 (5.5 MB)  TX bytes:380517 (380.5 KB)
```

Comment: well, what is output of ifconfig command ( run it in terminal and copy paste to your question). What hardware are you using ?

Comment: Just a moment. By hardware what do you mean ?

Comment: i ment which laptop are you using ( model name ). But running this and pasting output here should be enough . `lspci | grep Ethernet` 
Do you use dhcp on your network ? Is it configured properly ? Have you tried changing MAC address in case that your ISP allows connecting only from one MAC address ?

Comment: Just a moment.. I think everything is ok configurated at start when i put the cable network starts, but something happend and now it doesn't start on the laptop.I didn't touch any of the config things about eth0

Comment: The output is Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)

Comment: @alerbeham Did you test the network cable on another system to confirm that it works, and that its not just your system?

Comment: I told that it works on my pc

Comment: Just wanted to make sure - I didn't see a clear definition that you tested the cable on another system - laptops are considered PCs too :P

Comment: Any ideas to go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in your ifconfig output, your eth0 interface is working (transmitting and receiving) but can't get an IP from your ISP. Does your ISP allow multiple connections (and gives multiple IP)? You can try to disconnect the wi-fi interface and see if cable connects.

UPDATE: you can try to put in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo eth0 wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

and restart networking with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` (or reboot)

Comment: This is not working :(

Comment: updated answer with another try